# What can I do to roleplay better in DnD?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, roleplaying, player-characters

I have been playing D&D for nearly 2 years with the same character, a female elven monk who is a sage librarian.  I was previously in a party where role playing wasn't pushed as much as it is in my current party. So we basically played any way we wanted but in my current group it's different.

The party I am currently in consists of 4 guys, including the DM, and myself, the only girl. One of them is a bard, the other a druid, and the last is a fighter. They all have rich backstories and interesting characters while mine falls kind of flat.

The other members have also been playing with each other for a long time, are friends outside of the party, and just find roleplaying to be a bit easier. This has lead to my DM reaching out to me and asking me to try to role play better. I am kind of having difficulty with this because I have not played in a way that roleplaying is necessary rather than encouraged.

I enjoy the occasional roleplaying but I am more into the actual fighting aspects of the game. This makes it kind of difficult to get into character. I just kind of need some strategies, mainly ideas of what other people do and have done, for fleshing out a character in such a way that role playing is made a bit easier or at the least, a bit more enjoyable for all.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get an idea for how a Q&A site in the SE format is different from a forum.  We need some more detail to help, and even with that this may be too broad of a question for this format.  Please edit into your post your character's background, how many people are in the party, and what each character class is.  If the question gets closed, we do have [a list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566) that we recommend for question seeking ideas and opinions.

Comment: [A related question is here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110965/22566)

Comment: I rolled back the edit in which you removed the D&D 5e tag. I don't know if this question will be narrowed down to be less broad, but even if it is, how you are allowed and able to roleplay is heavily dependent on the RPG system.

Comment: It may be useful to add some of the defining features of your character and ask specifically how to better play them out at the table. General roleplaying advice will be far too broad for this site.